# Datatable custom filter to remove rows with duplicate data on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am creating a comparison table and want to be able to hide all of the rows in a datatable that have the same column 2 & and column 3 value. I have created a custom button that runs the below js:

```
action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {                           
   var rows = $("#compare").find("tbody tr"); //find all rows

   rows.each(function() {
     var thisRow = $(this),
     value1 = thisRow.find("#1"),
     value2 = thisRow.find("#2");

     if(value1.text() == value2.text()){
       thisRow.hide();
     }

   });
}
```

This does hide the rows on the current dataTable page that are duplicates, but still shows 10 results for that page even though all 10 are hidden. I read a few other questions, most of the answers recommended that a custom filter be applied to the rows due to serverside paging?

I would like the button to regenerate the table with only values where `value1 !== value2`, so if there are 25 results and 20 of them are duplicates, the table would be reloaded with `showing results 1 to 5 of 5 entries.`

datatable creation ->

```
success: function(data){
        var Table = document.getElementById("compare");
        Table.innerHTML = "";
        $("#compare").append(data);
        $("#compare").DataTable({
            dom: 'Bfrtip',                
            buttons: [
                {
                    text: 'My button',
                    action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {                           
                        
                        var rows = $("#compare").find("tbody tr"); //find all rows

                        rows.each(function() {
                            var thisRow = $(this),
                            value1 = thisRow.find("#1"),
                            value2 = thisRow.find("#2");

                            if(value1.text() == value2.text()){
                                $(this).hide();
                            }

                        });

                        //$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
                        //    return table.row(dataIndex).nodes().to$().attr('excluded') != 'true'
                        //})
                        
                        
                    }
                }
            ]
        });

    }
```

Comment: Approaach is wrong to deal with rows as DOM elements. You want to filter the actual data through the plugin api and have it render the rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **@charlietfl** already told you, you should go for the jQuery DataTable **filter** approach.

Something like this:

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    ordering: false
});

$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
    
     if(data[2] == data[3])
        return false;
     else
        return true;
});

function removeDuplicates() {
   table.draw();
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="removeDuplicates()">Remove Duplicates</button>
<br><br>
<table id="example" class="display" style="width: 100%;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Age 1</th>
            <th>Age 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
            <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
            <td>47</td>
            <td>47</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>42</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ashton Cox</td>
            <td>Junior Technical Author</td>            
            <td>66</td>
            <td>66</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Bradley Greer</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>41</td>
            <td>20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Dai Rios</td>
            <td>Personnel Lead</td>
            <td>35</td>
            <td>37</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>30</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Yuri Berry</td>
            <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
            <td>40</td>
            <td>27</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Caesar Vance</td>
            <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>22</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Doris Wilder</td>
            <td>Sales Assistant</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>23</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: That worked for me, thank you. Now I'm running into the issue where its holding onto the data even after I remove one column. So, I'll select 3 items to compare, the compare button works great. I then remove one item, but the compare button is still seeing three options.